# redirect file to the program execute by execv()?

Tags: c, unix, exec

I'm writing a C program where I fork() read a file in parent and pass to child via a pipe, then in child redirect the file receive from the pipe to the program I want to execv,

For example, if I exec /bin/less with doc.txt, I will read doc.txt in parent and pass to child, then execute less with the string receive from the read end of pipe. 
Everything else is ok, except the execv() part.

I have read the man page for execv(), but it doesn't really help on doing this...

Any help?

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what you're trying to do. Mind posting some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any forked child share the parents file descriptors, you can simply redirect stdin to a file descriptor with [dup2()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) then just fork and exec away in your child process.

When the child process reads data from stdin, it'll read from the file descriptor you opened (which could be a descriptor to your doc.txt).